# USB 2.0 wireless 802.11N didn't work

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, ethernet

On Ubuntu 18.04, the RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller didn't work. But it is showing as Ethernet device. Following are some detail.

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 6c:62:6d:56:af:9d
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8101 driverversion=1.035.03-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:17 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:fdfff000-fdffffff memory:fdfe0000-fdfeffff memory:febe0000-febfffff
```

```
$ sudo lspci -v | grep -A20 Ethernet 
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
I/O ports at e800 [size=256]
Memory at fdfff000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at fdfe0000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at febe0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
Capabilities: [ac] MSI-X: Enable- Count=2 Masked-
Capabilities: [cc] Vital Product Data
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-ff-ff-00-00
Kernel driver in use: r8101
Kernel modules: r8101
```

```
$ lspci -nn | grep Ethernet 
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
```

Comment: try `ip link set eth0 up`

Comment: I just tried, nothing seems to change.